# Need help with Test Class for PageRef

Tags: code-coverage

Class-

```java
public with sharing class CaseContractPageController {
    public string selectedRecordType {get;set;}

    public CaseContractPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public pagereference newPage(){
        recordType rec = [select id from RecordType where developerName=: selectedRecordType AND sObjectType ='Case'] ;

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType='+rec.id+'&ent=Case');
        pageRef.setredirect(true);  
        return pageRef;
    }

    public pagereference cancelPage(){
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('www.google.com');
        pageRef.setredirect(true);  
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Test Class-

```java
static testMethod void newPageTestMethod() {
    Account recAccount = new Account(Name='TestAccount');
    Insert recAccount;
    Case recCase = new Case(AccountId=recAccount.Id, RecordTypeId ='012q00000009TUM');
    insert recCase;

    Apexpages.standardcontroller sc = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(recCase);
    CaseContractPageController cseController = new CaseContractPageController (sc);
    Id  recordTypeId = [select id from RecordType where Name='LR - NDA'].id;

    cseController.selectedRecordType  = 'LR - NDA';

    pagereference pagecase = Page.CaseContract;
    Test.setcurrentpage(pagecase);

    system.debug('recordTypeIdTest'+recordTypeId );

    pagecase.getParameters().put('rec.id',recordTypeId );


    try{
        cseController.newPage();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

+edit:

Second attempt, still failing

```java
static testMethod void newPageTestMethod() {

    Account recAccount = new Account(Name='TestAccount');
    Insert recAccount;

    Id  recordTypeId = [select id from RecordType where DeveloperName='LR_NDA'].id;

    Case recCase = new Case(AccountId=recAccount.Id, RecordTypeId =RecordTypeId);
    insert recCase;


    Apexpages.standardcontroller sc = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(recCase);
    CaseContractPageController cseController = new CaseContractPageController (sc);

    pagereference pagecase = Page.CaseContract;
    Test.setcurrentpage(pagecase);

    pagecase.getParameters().put('rec.id',RecordTypeId);
    cseController.newPage(); 
}
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I am able to cover for cancelPage() but no luck with newPage().
I'm unable to get coverage for -PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType='+rec.id+'&ent=Case');
    pageRef.setredirect(true);  
    return pageRef;

Comment: I've upvoted this because, while imperfect, OP included the code being tested and the test, and is continuing to engage with the community to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

That `try/catch` in your `newPageTestMethod()` is hiding errors from you, and you should remove it.

A large part of the purpose of having unit tests is so that you have something to notify you when something goes wrong in your code. Having the `try/catch` defeats that purpose.

Without that `try/catch` in the way, I'd expect you'd be getting an error on the following line

```java
recordType rec = [select id from RecordType where developerName=: selectedRecordType AND sObjectType ='Case'] ;
```

I suspect the issue is due to the difference between `Name` and `DeveloperName`.
The `Name` of your record type is "LR - NDA", but your query is looking for the *`DeveloperName`* (which is likely "LR_-_NDA" or "LR_NDA", developer and api names generally replace whitespace and special characters with an underscore).

Since you attempt to pass the regular (label) name instead of the developer name, your query on `RecordType` is returning no rows. If you remove the `try/catch` from your test method, I'd expect you'll be greeted with a "NO_ROWS_FOR_ASSIGNMENT" error.

### Other advice

Generally speaking, `try/catch` doesn't have much of a place in unit tests. If your test method has a try/catch, you're probably doing something wrong.

The exception (pun intended) to that is when you are explicitly testing that your code *does* throw an exception. A small example:

```java
public class MyClass{
    @testVisible
    private static Boolean throwException = false;

    public class MyException extends Exception{}

    public MyClass(){
        if(MyClass.throwException){
            throw new MyException('I\'m an Exception!');
        }
    }
}

@isTest 
private class TestMyClass{
    @isTest
    static void testException(){
        MyClass.throwException = true;

        Boolean exceptionThrown = false;

        try{
            MyClass testInstance = new MyClass();
        }catch(MyClass.MyException e){
            exceptionThrown = true;
        }

        System.assertEquals(true, exceptionThrown, 'Expected an exception to be thrown');
    }

}
```

In that example, the try/catch is used to handle the exception so we can continue on to making the assertion (to verify that an exception of the expected type was thrown). That leads into my next piece of advice...

The most important part of unit tests is to *verify that your code behaves the way you expect it to*. To do this, you need to use *assertions*. Whatever output the code you're testing has (return values, modifying class variables, inserting/updating records, etc...), you should make an assertion to verify that the change you think should have occurred actually did occur.

In your particular case, you should think about asserting that your method doesn't return a null `PageReference`, and that the url of your `PageReference` matches your expectations (contains your record type id).

### edits

The issue that you're facing now is that your test method isn't setting `selectedRecordType` in your controller/extension. If you look at the code that you're trying to test, this is the variable that your code is expecting to be the `developerName`.

Comment: Thanks Derek, for the advice and I was greeted with the error as I removed the exception and so I changed the parameter I am passing to as DeveloperName but even then I am getting List has no rows for assignment to sObject error.

Comment: this is the updated test class for newPage method()

Comment: @PrudhviP Trying to add code to comments doesn't really work out so well (limited length and formatting options). Instead, you should [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/218516/edit) to include these extra details. I'd recommend keeping your original test method as part of your question (it adds important context for other people reading your question), and adding the new version underneath. Also, if you highlight your code, and click the "{}" button (or press ctrl + k, or cmd + k on macs) the code will appear as a block (which makes it easier to read).

Comment: Thanks Derek. Sorry, I am fairly new and this would be my first question and I am already meesing things up!

Comment: @PrudhviP It does take some time to learn how to use the site (and markdown). As long as you show effort to improve, people will generally be patient with you. The [help page on formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [ask] should be helpful.

Comment: Will do @derekF, thanks! :)
And for my issue would there be something that I am missing and need to correct?

Comment: @PrudhviP I edited my answer after I went back and edited the addition that you made to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DerekF I was able to set the selectedRecordType and get the code coverage.

Comment: @PrudhviP don't forget about adding assertions next! Your code not causing an exception, and your code producing correct output are two separate things. Salesforce only enforces code coverage, but truly the most useful part of unit testing is being able to make assertions to "prove" that your code meets requirements. Having assertions also makes it easier to identify errors that happen because of changes that will be made in the future (failing tests are easier to debug than incorrect records).